# Delphi XE3 third party VCL components in the XE4?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe4

I use Delphi XE3 and I want to migrate to the Delphi XE4. Can I use the same third party components as I used in XE3 in XE4? In previous versions happened many changes, which precluded the use of previous versions of third party components.

Comment: Why would you need to use previous versions of the VCL? Every version of Delphi comes with its own version of the VCL.

Comment: You can never ever ever use the VCL from one version of Delphi in another version. However, it is generally 100% backward compatible. So you don't have to. But I suspect from your comments you should edit your question to say "Third Party VCL components". I edited your question to fix your inadvertent confusing question.

Comment: I mean third party VCL. Sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must re-compile your project in XE4, using XE4's VCL.

If by "XE3 VCL" you are actually referring to third-party VCL components, then they need to be compiled and installed in XE4 before they can be used in XE4 projects.

This is true of just about every Delphi version (D2007 being the only exception, as it was binary compatible with D2006).

Comment: Yes, I am referring to vcl third party because when I migrated from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE3, VCL was totally incompatible, requiring me to buy all the third-party VCL I use.
So if I have the source code, I just need to recompile VCL third party?

Comment: You may have to make some small changes to third party components but very little. I found almost NOTHING needed changing between XE2,XE3, and XE4.